# Keymap location /usr/share/kbd/keymaps or /usr/share/keymaps?

Tags: linux, keyboard-layout

Did something change or are some distros just different?  I see reference to both `/usr/share/kbd/keymaps` as well as `/usr/share/keymaps`

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

[Filesystem Hierarchy Standard 3.0](https://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/FHS_3.0/fhs/ch04s11.html) from year 2015 does not specify a standard location for keymaps, so it is possible that different distributions have different policies here.

- Debian (and related distros) seems to use `/usr/share/keymaps`.
- RHEL 9 uses `/usr/lib/kbd/keymaps`.

(feel free to edit in other distributions)